# Como separo el fondo de pagina en 2

Tags: javascript, html, css, div, diseño

Hola yo quiero poner 2 imagenes de fondo de la pagina web la mitad de la pagina de la imagen 1 y la otra mitad de la imagen 2 (aclaración no manejo javascript) y por ultimo quiero añadir una imagen mas chiquita en el centro como un logo

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar por ejemplo:

```
 <div id="fondo1">
       
 </div>
 <div id="fondo2">
 
 </div>
```

Y ya en el css poner en cada propiedad la direccion de la imagen que quieras.

Que seria como esto

```
#fondo1{    background-image: url(fondo1.gif);   }
#fondo2{    background-image: url(fondo2.png);   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

- Asignando el 50% a cada uno de los `div`
- Posicion `fixed` para que mantenga su posicion en relación a la ventana grafica.

```css
.split {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

/* Control the left side */
.left {
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("https://miro.medium.com/max/800/1*M_GDn6RXZSZC66kvrMHh5Q.png");
  background-size: 150px;
}

/* Control the right side */
.right {
  right: 0;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c3/Python-logo-notext.svg/800px-Python-logo-notext.svg.png");
  background-size: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="split left"></div>
<div class="split right"></div>
```

Comment: Gracias por ayudar enserio y mira que actualize la pregunta me ayudaris mucho si sabes hacer eso

Answer (score 0):

Una solución muy simple es usar solamente **CSS**, con varios `url()` separados por coma.

Por ejemplo, no se debe usar `background-image` si no que solamente `background`, y con la url() separados por comas.

```
background: url(), url();
```

Después de cada `url()` se debe especificar donde ubicar el fondo: `top` o `right` o `bottom` o `left` seguidamente y opcionalmente (aquí) el `no-repeat` (pudiendo establecer otra declaración: `background-repeat`):

```
background: url() top left no-repeat, url() top right no-repeat;
```

Lo siguiente y muy importante es definir las dimensiones de cada fondo: las medidas de cada imagen: `background-size`.
Es mejor usar la medida **vw** que se refiere a lo ancho de la pantalla, y **vh** lo alto de la pantalla; para ver cada imagen al lado del otro, uso **50vw** de ancho para cada imagen y el alto completo de la pantalla con **100vh**.

```
background-size: 50vw 100vh;
```

Por último y para mejorar todo, sería mejor poner el fondo como fijo, para que no se mueva, ya que solamente el fondo es mejor visto con **100vh** y al bajar la página, el fondo de imágen desaparece:

```
background-attachment: fixed
```

Aunque este ejemplo no es compatible con todas las pantallas, en especial para móviles (porque es muy angosto y largo), ya te tocaría modificar esa parte entre el **vw** y **vh** y las posiciones después de cada `url()`

```css
body {
background: url(https://placeimg.com/700/300/nature) top left no-repeat,
            url(https://placeimg.com/700/300/animals) top right no-repeat;
background-size: 50vw 100vh;
background-attachment: fixed;

/* Para hacer scroll */
min-height: 3000px
}
```

```html
            
<body></body>
```